# How to nest marshmallow schema using data from same source?

Tags: python, marshmallow

I want to group `contact_type` and `contact_value` into `contact` nested object in output for following model:

```
class Account(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'accounts'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    contact_type = sa.Column(sa.String)
    contact_value = sa.Column(sa.String)
```

This result is expected:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "contact": {
    "type": "phone",
    "value": "1234567"
  }
}
```

What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35881744/how-to-nest-some-parent-object-fields-when-serializing-objects-using-marshmallow

Answer (score 1):

```
ma = Marshmallow()

class AccountContactSchema(ma.Schema):
    type = ma.Str()
    value = ma.Str()

class AccountSchema(ma.Schema):
    id = ma.Int()
    contact = ma.Nested(AccountContactSchema)

account_schema = AccountSchema()
```

Comment: This won't load the contact_type or contact_value attributes of the object from the ORM

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the best way, but you can do this:

```
from marshmallow import fields

class AccountSchema(ma.Schema):
    id = ma.Int()
    contact = fields.Function(lambda x : {'type': x.contact_type, 'value': x.contact_value})
```

and use:

```
>>> acc = Account(id=1, contact_type="phone", contact_value="1234567")
>>> acc_dict, errors = AccountSchema().dump(acc)
>>> print acc_dict    
{u'contact': {'type': 'phone', 'value': '1234567'}, u'id': 1}
```

Or you can do in other styles of dict:

```
class AccountSchema(ma.Schema):
    id = ma.Int()
    contact = fields.Function(lambda x : {x.contact_type : x.contact_value})
```

This will result:

```
{u'contact': {'phone': '1234567'}, u'id': 1}
```

Take a look at [Custom Fields](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custom_fields.html)